# Possible Feynman diagram for $\tau^+ \rightarrow p \mu^+ \mu^-$ and $\tau^+ \rightarrow \bar{p} \mu^+ \mu^+$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory, standard-model, elementary-particles

I want to know the possible Feynman diagram for these two lepton family, lepton and baryon number violating tau decays. These decays are forbidden in the Standard Model. But the further extension of the SM could give rise to this kind of decays. Here $B-L = 0,2$. Any answer is most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the part with the anti. Check the formatting - you might \bar{}.

Comment: Do you have any particular SM extension in mind or do you just want to have an example for one possible way?

Comment: I am working in experimental particle physics. I am not very good in any  BSM physics models.  It may be possible with some higher dimension operators.  Also, these decays may proceed with the help of leptoquarks.